# Is spinach which has bolted as unusable as bolted lettuce?

Tags: harvesting, bolting, spinach

Bolted lettuce is famously unusable because your sweet salad leaves turn bitter.

But does the same apply to spinach? It's a lettuce type crop (and equally prone to bolting in hot weather) but it's basically a bitter leaf anyway and typically cooked to a mush (a nice mush, if spinach is your thing, but still a mush) anyway, so does it really matter if additional bitterness has entered the plant?

Comment: Oh... please don't cook your poor spinach to a mush! It's got such a wonderful texture. Roll a stack of (non-bolted?) spinach, chard, and/or kale leaves into a tube and slice 1cm thick. Sprinkle in your salad bowl with a drizzle of ranch dressing. Still think it's too bitter? Same prep, maybe cut a little wider. Heat some olive oil in a wok. Stir fry some crushed garlic and a bit of red pepper flakes; add the leaves *just* until they *start* to wilt (*not mush!*). Serve hot with some pineapple chunks and just a *bit* of soy sauce.

Comment: Or, if you're going to make mush, it deserves to be with ricotta in, say, a nice veg lasagna... ;)

Answer (score 4):

Yeah, but mainly because of the pollen which get everywhere and coats the plants. I don't think the leaves tasted particularly bad.  Not picking it in a timely manner is why I didn't plant spinach this year.  Last year I used my bolted spinach to [make soup](http://livingsmallblog.com/2007/06/26/bolted-spinach-soup/)

Comment: what about the pollen? Is your answer specific to those with  pollen allergies?

Comment: Nope, it's specific to people who don't enjoy eating pollen